# moving vector from class (vs 2013 compiler)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, move-semantics

I want to move vector from class

```
class Data
{
    public:
        std::vector<int> && getValues() {return std::move(values);}

    private:
        std::vector<int> values;
};
```

I use vs2013 complier and, as i know, it does not support ref-qualifiers. How can I move safety?

```
Data d;
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;
...
v1=d.getValues(); //i want copy
v2=std::move(d.getValues());  // i want move
```

Comment: Why do you want to *move* a class member outside of the object in the first place?

Comment: afaik moving leaves the moved from object in an unusable state. Either I am wrong or it is a bit strange to move a private member

Comment: @tobi303 It is left in a unspecified but valid state (you can reuse it).

Comment: I would first rename `getValues`by `takeValues`.

Comment: @InternetAussie for perfomance, move is faster

Comment: @Timur but it is also taster to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: So does vs2013 not have `std::move()`?

Comment: @Walter: vs 2013 doesn't have `std::vector<int>&& getValues() &&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return by normal reference:

```
class Data
{
public:
    const std::vector<int>& getValues() const {return values;}
    std::vector<int>& getValues() {return values;}

    // And if you really want to move member, you may do
    std::vector<int> takeValues() {return std::move(values);}
private:
    std::vector<int> values;
};
```

Then you may use

```
Data d;
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;
//...
v1 = d.getValues(); // copy
v2 = std::move(d.getValues()); // move
// Or alternatively:
v2 = d.takeValues(); // move
```

Comment: Good. But what to do if i want const referance `const std::vector<int>& getValues() {return values;}`, because of safety?

Comment: @Timur You can't move from a `const` instance as moving is a modifying process.

Comment: You have the 3 ways to got your member correctly. Not sure what you want after your comment. (and your method should be `const` in your comment).

Comment: @Jarod42 you have gotten. I want to distinguish safety copy and unsafety move

Comment: @Timur: `std::move` is explicit, so you are ok.

Comment: @Jarod42 I suppose it is better to use two function
`const std::vector<int>& getValues() const {return values;}` and `std::vector<int> takeValues() {return std::move(values);}`,
otherwise `auto& v=d.getValues()` gives ability to change `data.values` by modifing `v`(if use `std::vector<int>& getValues() {return values;}` ) Am i right?